# Picker functionality is not working as expected

Tags: codenameone

When the actionListener is used in Picker, the cancel btn is not working as expected. At the begining, if you cancel the picker, getSelectedStringIndex gives -1 which is fine. If I click 1st one and then click ok, it gives index 0. From here, each time cancel is clicked, it returns index 0. It should have returned -1 since cancel is clicked. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
periodPicker.addActionListener(e -> {

    String periodString = "";
    if (periodPicker.getSelectedStringIndex() == 0) {
        periodString = "3";
    } else if (periodPicker.getSelectedStringIndex() == 1) {
        periodString = "6";
    } 

    if (!periodString.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("index " + periodPicker.getSelectedStringIndex());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancel isn't reset. Once you made a selection and click cancel the old selection is returned. You would need to add a separate UI element that would clear the selection value by setting it to null. It won't integrate in the `Picker` UI itself as that UI is natively rendered.

Comment: how can i know if the user clicks cancel or ok button in the picker.. If I can get smth there, I think I can make it work.

Comment: I solved this by comparing the value returned by the picker with the previous value, and ignore the picker action if there was no change.

Comment: Generally the native picker API should return the default value in case of a cancel but that applies to the device only API which is in `Display`. One of the things I'd like to do is implement the Android style native picker in pure Java so people would be able to customize and theme them properly. Unfortunately, that's a bit of work...